# How to utilize unique slugs for plugin elements that extend the BaseElement class

Tags: plugins, slug

I have my slug saving to the `element_i18n` table but it's not unique. When saving a non-unique slug using the default Craft entries, the slug gets appended with "-1".

How can I extend the default functionality for a slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad, I realize my initial question is a bit vague, oops! I did however find a solution to why my localized slugs for my plugin element weren't being saved as a unique string.

I traced through `ElementHelper::setUniqueUri()` and figured out I was missing the `getUrlFormat()` function. Also to make sure I include `{slug}` in my `urlFormat` string in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to tell what you're trying to do from the description and without seeing some code examples, but internally Craft uses [ElementHelper::setValidSlug()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/ElementHelper#setValidSlug-detail) and [ElementHelper::setUniqueUri()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/ElementHelper#setUniqueUri-detail) to perform those tasks.

Whether you need to use them directly or call a Craft method that uses them is hard to say without more context.